# Get max or min value

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can I get the max or min value of one image?
I don't know what's the function is in GEE.
I have to use this for vegetation coverage
For example:
[1,2,3,
 4,5,6,
 7,8,9]
max:9;min:1

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-121.52324218749999, 37.901687004454395],
      [-121.46831054687499, 37.42335315973017],
      [-120.86406249999999, 37.46696534545472],
      [-120.89702148437499, 37.98832531444019]]]);

var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MCD43A4_NDVI")
var modis_filtered = modis.filterDate("2010-01-01","2010-04-01").median().clip(geometry)

print(modis_filtered.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
      geometry: geometry,
      scale : 250
      }))
```

More info can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Honestly, I used Landsat to caculate NDVI, but I think they are the same.

Comment: This is just an example - you can perform the reduce operation on any `ee.Image`,  or `ee.ImageCollection` whether it be landsat, modis, seneinel, or others. Try substituting your image instead of the `modis_filtered` variable and examine the results.